# How to Speed Up Mongodump, Dump Not Finishing

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

In trying to run a database dump using a query from a db of about 5 billion, the progress bar times seem to indicate that this dump won't finish in any reasonable time (100+ days).  The query also froze after it seems to have ended at 0%, around 22 or so hours later - the line after is a metadata.json line.

The dump line is:

```
mongodump -h myHost -d myDatabase -c mycollection --query "{'cr' : {\$gte: new Date(1388534400000)}, \$or: [ { 'tln': { \$lte: 0., \$gte: -100.}, 'tlt': { \$lte: 100, \$gte: 0} }, { 'pln': { \$lte: 0., \$gte: -100.}, 'plt': { \$lte: 100, \$gte: 0} } ] }"
```

And my last few lines of output was (typed as I can't post images yet.)

```
[timestamp] Collection File Writing Progress: 10214400/5066505869 0% (objects)
[timestamp] Collection File Writing Progress: 10225100/5066505869 0% (objects)
[timestamp] 10228391 objects
[timestamp] Metadata for database.collection to dump/database/collection.metadata.json
```

Any thoughts to help improve performance or any idea on why this is taking so long?

Comment: Write this query in mongo shell, use explain() to see what the query plan is - it might be that the query is slow by itself

Comment: In addition to the output of explain(), can you also confirm what version of MongoDB you are using? How many output results are you expecting from your 5 billion source documents? It's unclear if the ~10 million objects might actually be your full result set as the last line referencing `metadata.json` is normally emitted when the dump completes for a given collection.

Comment: Hi all, So even the .explain() is taking a very long time (couple hours+) to run.  Is this usual?  I even tried simplifying the .explain() to just a location filter, (if the x-coordinates and y-coordinates are both within a range) and still takes a while.  Will continue to run and update.

Answer (score 20):

I've just faced this issue, and the problem is that `mongodump` is basically not very smart. It's traversing the `_id` index, which likely means lots and lots and lots of random disk access. For me, dumping several collections, `mongodump` was simply crashing due to cursor timeouts.

The issue is also described here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-845. However, that doesn't really provide a great resolution part from "Works as Designed". It's possible there's something funny about the index, but I think in my case it was just a large enough collection that the amount of disk access was seriously hard work for my poor little Mac Mini.

One solution? Shut down writing and then use `--forceTableScan`, which makes a sequential pass through the data, which might well be faster than using the `_id` index if you are using a custom `_id` field (I was).

The docs are a bit sketchy, but it reads as if the normal `mongodump` behaviour might be to traverse the `_id` index using a snapshot and then filter by the query. In other words, it might be traversing all 5 billion records in `_id` order, not stored data order, i.e., randomly, to complete the query. So you might be better building a tool that reads from a real index and writes directly.

For me, `--forceTableScan` was enough, and it meant (a) it actually completes successfully, and (b) it's an order of magnitude or more faster.