# Is read and insert operation faster than dump in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, delete-row, dump

I need to clean a mongodb collection of 200Tb, and delete older timstamp. I am trying to build a new collection from the new, and run a delete query, since, running a del on the present collection that is in use, will slow down the other requests to it. I have thought of cloning a new collection either by taking a dump of the following collection, or by create a read and and write script, such that, it will read from the present collection and write to the cloned collection. My question is is a read/write operation of a batch ex: 1000 read and write faster than a dump ?

EDIT:
I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/882304/speed-up-mongodumpmongorestore), [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135478/large-mongodump-followed-by-mongorestore) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017653/how-to-speed-up-mongodump-dump-not-finishing/44768365#44768365) article, and want to know, if writing a script in the above mentioned way the same as creating a ssh pipe of read and write ? ex: is a node/python script to fetch 1000 rows from a collection and insert that to a clone collection the same as `ssh *** ". /etc/profile; mongodump -h sourceHost -d yourDatabase … | mongorestore -h targetHost -d yourDatabase` ?

Comment: How many data you need to delete? How do you create the clone? (do you have sufficient disc space for 2 times 200 TB?)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am not sure on how many data to delete, all the datas before a particular timestamp would be deleted, we can asume 50-80TB will be deleted. yes, we have sufficient disc space for the operation.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit added update at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this approach:

- Rename the collection. Your application will immediately create a new empty collection with the old name when it tries to insert some data. You may create some indexes.
- Run `mongoexport/mongoimport` to import the **valid** data, i.e. skip the outdated.

Yes, in general `mongodump/mongorestore` might be faster, however at `mongoexport` you can define a query and limit the data which is exported. Could be like this:

```
mongoexport --uri "..." --db=yourDatabase --collection=collection --query='{timestamp: {$gt: ISODate("2022-01-010")}}' | mongoimport --uri "..." --db=yourDatabase --collection=collection --numInsertionWorkers=10
```

Utilize parameter `numInsertionWorkers` to run multiple workers. It will speed up your inserts.

So you run a sharded cluster? If yes, then you should use `sh.splitAt()` on the new collection, see [How to copy a collection from one database to another in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554762/how-to-copy-a-collection-from-one-database-to-another-in-mongodb/67077465#67077465)

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the number of process/workers to allocate for this task and the time it will take ?

Comment: Maybe derive from the number of CPU's. Let's say 5 times CPU

Comment: Seems a great solution, however there is one downside to this and that is, if the ssh command/ piping fails or gets aborted for some reason, then the copy will be incomplete, is there a suggestion for that ? can we make that into a background running process until the completion ?

Comment: With the normal command, i.e. start with appending `&` and optionally `nohup`. Ensure to catch the output which shows progressing. If it fails, the simply run it again, existing documents will fail, because `_id` must be unique.